# Rank of submatrices: clarify an apparent contradiction

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Consider the matrix
$$
A\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
B & C & D\end{pmatrix}^\top \begin{pmatrix}
B & C & D\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
B^\top B & B^\top C &  B^\top D \\
C^\top B & C^\top C &  C^\top D \\
D^\top B & D^\top C &  D^\top D \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Consider the following three observations. It seems to me that they lead to a contradiction. Hence, some (all) of them should be wrong. Could you point out the mistake?

**(1)** If $A$ is invertible, then it does **not** imply that every square submatrix of $A$ is invertible. For example, we could have that $A$ is invertible but the submatrix
$$
Q\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
B^\top B  &  B^\top D \\ 
D^\top B  &  D^\top D \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is not invertible.

**(2)** $A$ is invertible if and only if $\begin{pmatrix}
B & C & D\end{pmatrix}$ is full column rank.

**(3)** If $\begin{pmatrix}
B & D \end{pmatrix}$ is not full column rank, then $\begin{pmatrix}
B & C& D \end{pmatrix}$ is not full column rank.

---

The contradiction is the following:

If $\begin{pmatrix}
B & D \end{pmatrix}$ is not full column rank (which holds if and only if $Q$ is invertible), then by (3) $\begin{pmatrix}
B & C& D \end{pmatrix}$ is not full column rank. In turn, by (2), $A$ is not invertible. This contradicts (1).

Comment: (2) is false.  $A$ is never invertible, regardless of $B,C,D$.

Comment: (sorry for the earlier mistaken comment) Do I have this right: your argument is that if A is invertible then (BCD) is full column rank, so (BD) is full column rank, so that matrix Q is invertible? That doesn't contradict (1) because there are lots of square submatrices not of the form of Q.

Comment: @Ruy I don't get your point, sorry. Could you clarify?

Comment: @MatthewTowers Yes, I see. Thanks. Can we ex-ante say which submatrices of $A$ will necessarily have to be invertible if $A$ is invertible?

Comment: great question, I don't know the answer I'm afraid. For a general A surely you can say nothing, but maybe for this special form.

Comment: I suppose that (by my arguments) the three submatrices $\begin{pmatrix} B & C \end{pmatrix}' \begin{pmatrix} B & C \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} B & D \end{pmatrix}' \begin{pmatrix} B & D \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} C & D\end{pmatrix}' \begin{pmatrix} C & D \end{pmatrix}$ have to be invertible if $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @Ruy (2) is true. For an example where $A$ is invertible, consider for  instance what happens if $B,C,D$ are consecutive columns of an identity matrix of size at least $3$.

Comment: @TEX Of your three statements, only (3) is false.

Comment: @BenGrossmann. Thanks. How is that possible? If the columns of $\begin{pmatrix} B & D\end{pmatrix}$ are linearly dependent, then also the columns of $\begin{pmatrix} B & D & C\end{pmatrix}$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: @TEX You're right, never mind. I was thinking "full rank", not "full column rank".

Comment: @TEX (1) is technically correct as written, but you use it to reach a false conclusion. As it turns out, if $A$ is invertible, then it is positive definite, which means that all of its **principal submatrices** must be positive definite (and therefore invertible). So for example, if $A$ is invertible, then 
$$
\pmatrix{B^TB & B^TD\\ D^TB & D^TD}
$$ 
must be invertible. The definition of a "principal submatrix" is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Submatrix).

Comment: @Ben, thanks for pointing out my mistake.  I was under the wrong impression that $B,C,D$ were square matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**. The first version of this answer was written under the misunderstanding that  *full column rank* means
that the columns generate the space where they live.  The OP has later called my attention to the fact that some people take it to
mean that instead, the columns are linearly independent.   I must say I find the latter terminology a bit misleading, so
I would try to avoid it by  refering to it by what it means.  Nevertheless, should  you like to further investigate
the terminology issue, I invite you to
compare

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)

and

[https://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/amwiki/index.php/FAQ:_What_does_it_mean_for_a_non-square_matrix_to_be_full_rank%3f](https://www.cds.caltech.edu/%7Emurray/amwiki/index.php/FAQ:_What_does_it_mean_for_a_non-square_matrix_to_be_full_rank%3f)

---

**Statement 1**.  Every submatrix of an invertible matrix is invertible.

*Verdict*: False.

*Counter example*: Let  $A$ be the $3×3$ identity matrix, and consider the  $2×2$ submatrix
$$
  \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0}
  $$
obtained by removing  the first row and the last  column of $A$.  It is obviously not invertible.

**Statement 1 (bis)**.  Every *principal* submatrix of a *positive* invertible matrix is invertible.

*Verdict*: True.

*Proof*: Let  $A$ be a positive invertible $n×n$ matrix.  A principal submatrix of $A$ is one that is obtained by removing some
rows, say the ones indexed by
$$
  k_1,k_2,…,k_p,
  $$
as well as some columns, but not just any columns, rather the columns indexed by the very same $k_1,k_2,…,k_p$.

Letting $R$ be the $n×(n-p)$ matrix whose columns  are the canonical basis vectors corresponding to the columns of $A$ which were **not**
removed, the corresponding submatrix may be expressed as $R^TAR$.

In order to prove that $R^TAR$ is invertible, it is enough to prove it is injective, so suppose $x$ is a ($n-p)$-column
matrix such that $R^TARx=0$.  Then
$$
  0 = ⟨R^TARx,x⟩ =
  ⟨A^{1/2}Rx,A^{1/2}Rx⟩ =
  \|A^{1/2}Rx\|^2,
  $$
so $A^{1/2}Rx=0$, and hence $ARx=0$, as well.  Since $A$ is injective, then $Rx=0$, but $R$ is also injective, so
$x=0$.  QED

---

**Statement 2**.  $A$ is invertible if and only if $\pmatrix{B & C & D}$ has linearly independent columns.

*Verdict*: True.

*Proof*: Denoting by the matrix $\pmatrix{B & C & D}$ simply by $E$, suppose that
$Ax=0$.  Then
$$
  0 = ⟨Ax,x⟩ = ⟨E^TEx,x⟩ =
  ⟨Ex,Ex⟩ = \|Ex\|^2,
  $$
so $Ex=0$, but since the columns of $E$ are linearly independent, one deduces that $x=0$.  QED

---

**Statement 3**.  If $\pmatrix{B & C}$ does  not have linearly independent columns then  $\pmatrix{B & C & D}$
does not have linearly independent columns.

*Verdict*: True.

*Proof*: Easy exercise.

Comment: No, the matrix $(1\ 1)$ has full column rank but its columns are not linearly independent.

Comment: I don't understand. The rank of $(1 ,1)$ intended as a row vector is $1$. It is not full column rank (it has two columns)!

Comment: Also in your answer: the row vector $(0,0,1)$ is not full colum rank (it has rank 1, instead of 3). Similarly, the row vector $(1,1,1)$ is not full colum rank (it has rank 1, instead of 3). Can you make examples with proper matrices, instead of vectors?

Comment: By full column rank I understand that the columns of the matrix generate the whole space where they lie.  Is that your underrtanding too?  My matrices are $1\times n$, and that is why they look like vectors.  For example $(1\ 1)$ is the 1x2 matrix with $a_{1,1}=a_{1,2}=1$.

Comment: The $1\times 2$ matrix $(1,1)$ has rank 1. Hence, it is not full column rank.

Comment: Correct.  And that is the dimension of $\mathbb R^1$, which is where the columns live.  So the rank is as big as it can be, hence called *full*.

Comment: Maybe you should spell out your defintion of full column rank in detail since we might be lost in terminology.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the confusion. By full column rank I mean rank = number of columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119932/discussion-between-ruy-and-tex).

Comment: From the Wikipedia page on rank https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra):  A matrix is said to have full rank if its rank equals the largest possible for a matrix of the same dimensions, which is the lesser of the number of rows and columns.

Comment: I'm in the chat.